# Area under scatter plot in python

Tags: python, plot, auc

I have two lists of number, xs and ys:

```
xs = [2, 5, 4]
ys = [6, 7, 8]
```

and use matplotlib library to plot them:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(xs, ys, 'bo')
```

Now I want to calculate area under the plot. I tried excel method:

```
sum = 0
for i in range(1, len(xs)):
    y = ys[i] + ys[i - 1]
    x = xs[i] - xs[i - 1]
    sum = sum + (y/2 * x)
```

but the answers aren't correct always. Then tried this:

```
from sklearn.metrics import auc
print('computed AUC using sklearn.metrics.auc: {}'.format(auc(xs,ys)))
```

but doesn't work for unsorted xs. So how can I calculate area under plot?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just sort the xs?

Comment: Actually I just wonder, if there is any way to calculate AUC without sort.

Comment: If you do not sort the points then the curve looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7emE.png). What do you want the AUC to be in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your integration formula appears correct for discrete points. I'm having trouble understanding how you want the area under the curve. By the way you wrote it, unsorted in the x-axis, it's getting the area under the line from point[0] to point [1] and then subtracting the area from point[1] to point[2]. If that's your case, then it does work.

If you want them the area directly underneath all 3-points, I'd sort xs. If you want the area under the curve, even considering it double backs on itself, I'd take the absolute value of x in the for loop. abs()

If you want the area under the curve without double counting the area between point[1] and point[2]. I'd write,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xs = [2, 5, 4]
x_sort = sorted(xs)
ys = [6, 7, 8]
sum = 0
plt.plot(xs, ys, 'bo')
plt.show()
for i in range(1, len(xs)):
    slope = (xs[i]-xs[i-1])/(ys[i] - ys[i-1])
    delta_x = x_sort[i] - x_sort[i - 1]
    delta_y =  ys[i - 1] + (ys[i-1] + delta_x * slope)
    sum = sum + (delta_y/2 * delta_x)
print(sum)
```

This takes the slope between the unsorted points and applies it between the sorted values, giving you the area directly beneath the graph if you connected the lines in the order of the [xs,ys] pairs.

I hope that helps answer your question.